# How to fix (the operation has timed out) error in sending emails using SMTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to develop a mailing system in the intranet web-based application that I am working on it for my company. I am developing it with ASP.NET and C#. The purpose of this system is to let the admin to be able to send emails to the users. I developed this system and I tested for 25 users and it works fine.

Now, I have 386 users in the database, so when I tried to send them emails, I got the following error:

> Exception Details: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has
>   timed out. 
>   I think this is because of ISP in my company blocked sending email to many users after a certain number of milliseconds. I tried to use SendAsync but I found it will not benefit me.

Also, I tried to maximize the execution timeout in the Web.config file as folloiwng:

```
<location path="Email4.aspx">
        <system.web>
                <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>
        </system.web>
</location>
```

but I failed. **So how to fix this problem?**

My Code-Behind (C#):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendEmailTOAllUser();
    }


    protected void SendEmail(string toAddresses, string fromAddress, string MailSubject, string MessageBody, bool isBodyHtml)
    {
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("MAIL.companyDomainName.com");
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("pssp@companyDomainName.com", "PMOD Safety Services Portal (PSSP)");

            // In case the mail system doesn't like no to recipients. This could be removed
            //msg.To.Add("pssp@companyDomainName.com");

            msg.Bcc.Add(toAddresses);
            msg.Subject = MailSubject;
            msg.Body = MessageBody;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
            //Response.Write(msg);
            sc.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    protected void SendEmailTOAllUser()

    {
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspEmail;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            var sbEmailAddresses = new System.Text.StringBuilder(1000);
            string quizid = "";

            // Open DB connection.
            conn.Open();

            string cmdText = "SELECT MIN (QuizID) As mQuizID FROM dbo.QUIZ WHERE IsSent <> 1";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // There is only 1 column, so just retrieve it using the ordinal position
                        quizid = reader["mQuizID"].ToString();

                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }

            string cmdText2 = "SELECT Username FROM dbo.employee";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText2, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var sName = reader.GetString(0);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sName))
                        {
                            if (sbEmailAddresses.Length != 0)
                            {
                                sbEmailAddresses.Append(",");
                            }
                            // Just use the ordinal position for the user name since there is only 1 column
                            sbEmailAddresses.Append(sName).Append("@companyDomainName.com");
                        }
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }

            string cmdText3 = "UPDATE dbo.Quiz SET IsSent = 1 WHERE QuizId = @QuizID";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText3, conn))
            {
                // Add the parameter to the command
                var oParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuizID", SqlDbType.Int);
                // Get a local copy of the email addresses
                var sEMailAddresses = sbEmailAddresses.ToString();


                    string link = "<a href='http://startQuiz.aspx?testid=" + quizid + "'> Click here to participate </a>";
                    string body = @"Good day, <br /><br />
                                <b> Please participate in the new short safety quiz </b>"
                                        + link +
                                        @"<br /><br />


                    SendEmail(sEMailAddresses, "", "Notification of New Weekly Safety Quiz", body, true);

                    // Update the parameter for the current quiz
                    oParameter.Value = quizid;
                    // And execute the command
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As first thing check with your company admin that you are usign rigth email server informatio (SMTP host, port, etc)

Comment: **Never** write `throw ex`.  It destroys the stack trace.  Get rid of that `catch` block.

Comment: I am using our company Mail Server. And according to their policy: please don't use the mail server to send many emails to many users at the same time. So what is the solution?

Comment: In that case, split the list of user in to smaller lists and send multiple emails. Also, you are marking you db records as sent before you even send the messages. You should only do that after you have successfully sent the message(s).

Comment: Interesting - you are only actually sending one email to a large group of recipients. How about creating a mail group with everyone in (say, "Safety Quiz Users") and just send one email with that as the "To" address?

Comment: @AlexMendez could you please tell me how to split the list of users into smaller lists and send multiple emails? I know that I will have a loop but I am not sure about the code. Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can split the list: (Please notes that this is pseudo code, i have not tested it)
Also, this will send an email per five users. You can increase the amount as you please.

```
var sEMailAddresses = sbEmailAddresses.ToString();
string link = "<a href='http://pmv/pssp/StartQuiz.aspx?testid=" + quizid + "'> Click here to participate </a>";
string body = @"Good day, <br /><br />
                                <b> Please participate in the new short safety quiz </b>"
                    + link +
                    @"<br /><br />
                            Also, give yourself a chance to gain more safety culture by reading the PMOD Newsletter.
                            <br /> <br /><br /> <br />
                            This email was generated using the <a href='http://pmv/pssp/Default.aspx'>PMOD Safety Services Portal (PSSP) </a>. 
                            Please do not reply to this email.
                            ";

int sendCount = 0;
List<string> addressList = new List<string>(sEMailAddresses.Split(','));
StringBuilder addressesToSend = new StringBuilder();

for (int userIndex = 0; userIndex < addressList.Count; userIndex++)
{
    sendCount++;
    if (addressesToSend.Length > 0)
        addressesToSend.Append(",");

    addressesToSend.Append(addressList[userIndex]);
    if (sendCount == 5 || userIndex == addressList.Count - 1)
    {
        SendEmail(addressesToSend.ToString(), "", "Notification of New Weekly Safety Quiz", body, true);
        addressesToSend.Clear();
        sendCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help and I really appreciate it. But I am confused now about where I should use your code. Could you just please tell me where I should use your code based in my above code?

Comment: Use it where you send your email with the SendEmail method. Instead of the addresses string, you will use your var sEMailAddresses = sbEmailAddresses.ToString();

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try it and come back to you if there is anything else. Sorry for asking a lot